# Show first array element - ReactJS

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript

I am developing a Quiz application using React / Typescript for the purpose of study.

I have the state called Quiz, it consists of:

```
interface QuestionData {
  id: number;
  question: string;
  explanation: string;
  options: OptionsData;
}
```

I would like to display only the first element of the array on the screen, I know that the way to do this would be:

```
<p>{quiz[0].question}</p>
```

But, in this way, I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'question' of undefined
```

If I print using console.log `(quiz[0].question)`, I get the desired return. Is there any other way? Or the form I thought was correct isn't it?

Full code below:

```
interface VideoInfo {
  video_id: number;
}

type OptionsData = any[];

interface QuestionData {
  id: number;
  question: string;
  explanation: string;
  options: OptionsData;
}

const Quiz: React.FC<VideoInfo> = video_id => {
  const [quiz, setQuiz] = useState<QuestionData[]>([]);

  const video = video_id;

  const getQuiz = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      await api.get(`/quiz/video/${video}`).then(response => {
        setQuiz(response.data);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      alert('error');
    }
  }, [video]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getQuiz();
  }, [getQuiz]);

  return (
    <Container>
      <ol>
        <li>
          <div className="question">
            {/* The error happens here: */}
            <p>{quiz[0].question}</p>
            <div>
              <Button type="button">A</Button>
              <Button type="button">B</Button>
              <Button type="button">C</Button>
              <Button type="button">D</Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Quiz;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In time when you try to get access to quiz[0] this element does not exists yet. Try to do something like that:

```
{quiz && quiz[0].question}
```

OR

```
{quiz[0]?.question}
```

That way you check if element exists before you try to get access to it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
        <p>{quiz[0]?.question}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the first, you can take it from the array this way:

```
const [first] = response.data;
```

You can get other indexes to:

```
const [first, second] = response.data;
```